# What is the difference between byte sizes for DD

Tags: dd

If I use the extreme byte size of 1 gb vs 1 mb for instance, on the hardware level, what is the difference? What does a byte size do if a constant stream of data is just getting written to the disk>?

Comment: 'Block size', not 'byte size'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is in how much data is read/written **at once**.

Programs rarely work with true constant streams – they usually read and write data in pieces: read 1 kB from input, write 1 kB to output, read 1 kB from input, write... So the `bs=` (**block** size) parameter for *dd* tells it how much data to read at once. It's often more efficient to ask the OS to read one 2 MB piece from disk, than to read sixteen 128 kB pieces. (Partly because the OS needs to do less work.) On the other hand, if you try to use `bs=16G`, then it will try to read a 16-gigabyte-sized block into RAM, then write it out at once; you'll probably run out of RAM.

It also depends on the storage media. **Disks are not streams** and aren't byte-addressed, whether magnetic or flash-based – they only allow reading block-sized pieces (where the block size depends on the hardware; many disks have it as 512 bytes or 4 kB). If the OS tries to read 100 bytes, the disk has to read the whole block anyway, and then discard the data. (It's even worse when writing: not sure with magnetic disks, but at least with flash, if you write 100 bytes the disk has to *read* the entire block, update it in memory, *then* write it.) So the block size used by `dd` matters here too – it'll be much faster if the block size used by `dd` is an exact multiple of the disk's block size. (Assuming there aren't any problems with partition alignment, that is.)